# Change Background Color of DataGrid Cell Flex 4.6

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I am trying to change the background color of my datagrid. I have the following which does change the color to red.... but only after I have clicked on the grid. I need the background color to start as red.

```
override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
            {
                super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
                var g:Graphics = graphics;
                g.clear();

                if (this.column.dataField == "data1")
                {

                    g.beginFill(0xFF0000);
                    g.drawRect(0, 0, unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
                    g.endFill();
                }
            }
```

This is inside my custom ItemRenderer

Comment: Sorry I am using Spark.

Answer (score 0):

Try call invalidateDisplayList function.

```
override public function prepare(hasBeenRecycled:Boolean):void {
      //do stuff

     this.invalidateDisplayList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had something wrong in my code. It is working now.